# How can Resharper help me to change a property's type throughout the entire solution?

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

I have the need to refactor a property "ID" from int to string. Since the ID is used in almost any part of my solution that could be a mess.

Besides simple assignments to the ID property I have parts like these:

**ID as parameter**

```
public void DoSomethingByID(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

**Assignments to typed Collections**

```
IList<int> validIDs = Validator.GetValidIDs(allIDs);
```

**References in other classes**

```
public class RelatedClass
{
    public int OwnID { get; set; }
    public int MyClassID { get; set; }
}
```

I'm excited about Resharper, but I don't have the overview about all its features that could help me here.

For instance there's the "Search and Replace with Pattern" functionality that could help me to replace all ID assignments from int to string. But I don't know how to use it with parameters and typed collections:

- replace all int parameters that contain 'id' in its name with string
- replace all `IEnumerables<int>` that contain 'id' in its name with string

If it's not an Resharper specific thing, of course any further help is appreciated

Comment: Resharper can't help you in automating this completely. It will do its best and leave the rest of the code in uncompilable state. Only way is "Leaning on the Compiler" i.e change the type and follow the compiler errors.

Comment: @Sriram I'm aware that Resharper can't do magic, my question was about assistance

Comment: What kind of assistance? I'm not sure what you expect us to answer here. Just change the type and the compiler will tell you exactly what to do.